# HTML pop up on click within WordPress

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, popup

In the WordPress theme I am using there is an area for HTML banner code. At the moment it contains the following:

```
<a href="http://bathcitysound.com/streaming/player.html">
<img src="my-image-code-goes-here" /></a>
```

All is well and good, and it functions as it should and when clicked it goes to the specific page. However, what I actually want to happen is when the image is clicked, it opens a pop up window of 300 pixels wide and 600 pixels height with this as the address:

```
http://bathcitysound.com/streaming/player.html
```

What should I add to the existing code to make that work?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<a href="javascript:window.open('http://bathcitysound.com/streaming/player.html','yourWindowTitle','width=300,height=600')">
    <img src="my-image-code-goes-here" />
</a>
```

You can try in your browser, by going to this URL:

```
javascript:window.open('http://bathcitysound.com/streaming/player.html','yourWindowTitle','width=300,height=600')
```